# SonarQube jenkins asks for login and password

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I am trying to anaylse my maven project through jenkins pipeline.

I have configured my SonarQube server instance in global settings of Jenkins with authorized token and server URL.

Following is the groovy script in my jenkinsfile :

```
stage('SonarQube analysis') {
            tools {
                   jdk "jdk-8u152"
                }
            steps {
                withSonarQubeEnv('My Sonar') {
                    sh 'mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar -Dsonar.login=XXXXXXXXX'
                }
            }
        }
```

When I build my project using jenkins I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project MyProject: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.
```

I would think this is sufficient to analyse the project. Not really sure what am I missing!

Comment: On the SonarQube server project, have you granted access to the specific user whose access token you have configured within Jenkins server? Also if the token is configured globally in Jenkins within your "My Sonar" sonarqube settings then you dont need to pass it again within the pipeline script.

Answer (score 13):

Okay I am on SonarQube 7.1 and this is how I did it:

1. Create a new user on SonarQube server. Browse to Administration -> Security -> Users -> Create User. Add login and Name and add a password.

[image]

1. Now login as the newly created user using the username and password. Click on the top right hand corner and click "MY Account" -> Security tab. Enter a token name (for example "Jenkins-Token") and click Generate token. Save this token.

[image]

3. Browse to your SonarQube project -> Administration -> Permissions.
4. Am assuming your project is private. Search for the above user that you added and add right permissions (Please grant execute analysis permission).

[image]

1. Go to your Jenkins Instance. Click on Manage Jenkins -> Configure System. Scroll down to your SonarQube Server section, either add a new server or edit the existing server to add the token that was generated to the "Server authentication token" field.
   [image]
2. In the pipeline script call the specific sonarqube server instance that you added in the previous step and pass the right paramters on command line. I didnt pass the authentication token on the command line as it is already configured within the sonarqube server details in 
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the elaborate answer. This is exactly what I have done too (apart from explicitly & deliberately adding the token in script). Even I was expecting this setup to work. This boggles me now!

Comment: Can you please copy the Jenkins console output here?

Comment: I have pasted it in my question. To add to the confusion, a gradle project which I analysed using same jenkins instance works.

Comment: Okay! So I found the issue. Its quite specific to my project. I have a parent pom that had some obsolete sonar properties. They were overriding my Jenkins global configuration and hence not using the token set in SonarQube server config in Jenkins. Silly stuff and that kept me troubled. Lesson learnt- properties in pom.xml override Jenkings global config parameters (in my case sonar authentication token was overridden by sonar.login and password properties in pom.xml)

Comment: Hello Isaiah4110 what is your Sonar plugin version? because I am  in 2.9 and not have the option Server Authentication Token